# Move a view on a circular path

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibezierpath

I'am trying to move a `UIImageView` on a circular path using `UIBezierPath` , my code works. but my problem with the start point of animation. the imageView start animating from the angle 0 from the path.
How can i change the animation starting point.

```
 CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height));

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.duration = FACE_DETECTED_TIME;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:@"easeInEaseOut"];
animation.repeatCount = 1;
//    animation.path = path;

UIBezierPath *bezierPath= [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.faceBorderImageView.frame];

animation.path = bezierPath.CGPath ;
 [self.tickImageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"test" ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an arc instead of circle...

```
-(UIBezierPath *)createArcWithRadius:(CGFloat)radius withStartAngle:(CGFloat)startAngle endAngle:(CGFloat)endAngle {

    UIBezierPath *path=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(radius, radius) radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];

    return path;
}
```

Comment: can you give me any example?